# StackOverflowError in AWS Glue while reading a million JSON files in Spark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The error happens if we try to load over a million JSON files in Spark from S3 as part of an AWS Glue job

```
spark_df = spark.read.load(s3_json_path, format='json')
```

700,000 files work fine, but over one million files result in a **StackOverflowError**. I have used Python 3, Glue 2.0, worker type G.1X and 10 workers (using G.2X or more workers to increase capacity does not help). The stack trace is

```
ERROR [main] glue.ProcessLauncher (Logging.scala:logError(70)): Error from Python:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/glue_job.py", line 107, in <module>
    spark_df = spark.read.load(s3_json_path, format='json')
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 166, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o70.load.
: java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

As a real StackOverflow error it fits perfectly to this site. Spark should be able to load a million files, where is the problem? What setting do I have to tweak to make it work?

Comment: please share your spark-submit command ?

Comment: The spark-submit command is done by AWS Glue. I use a Python script which uses `boto3.client('glue').start_job_run(..)` to start the Glue job. The script itself is provisioned by Terraform and the only commit command it uses is `job.commit()` at the end where job is defined from the Glue context :-/

Comment: are you running spark in cluster mode or local mode ?

Comment: In AWS Glue. As I understand it it allows a serverless execution of Spark by a cluster of "workers". By default the number of workers is 10 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job.html

Comment: hard yakka these types of things

Comment: You may want to try increasing Java stack size of Spark executors by setting `--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Xss1M"` or smth like that. No clue how can it be done in glue :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a solution but I managed to find a workaround. Apparently Spark/PySpark has a problem reading too many files from S3. A number of pages have explained [how many small files from S3 should not be pulled in Spark](http://www.pjrt.co/2015/05/11/how-not-to-pull-from-s3.html). It looks like [big data has a small files problem](https://garrens.com/blog/2017/11/04/big-data-spark-and-its-small-files-problem/). What we can do as a workaround is to [read multiple JSON files from S3 in parallel](https://wrightturn.wordpress.com/2015/07/22/getting-spark-data-from-aws-s3-using-boto-and-pyspark/) by using Boto3 and custom functions:

```
import json
import boto3

# read all JSON filenames from S3 using Boto3 & pagination
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)
file_list = []
for page in pages:
    for obj in page['Contents']:
        file_list.append(obj['Key'])

# it is important to define the S3 client *inside* the function
# because the S3 client is not serialisable
def load_json(key):
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    json_data = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)['Body'].read()
    return json.loads(json_data)

# read the JSON files in parallel by a custom loading function
data = sparkContext.parallelize(file_list).map(load_json)
dataSchema = StructType([StructField("name", StringType(), True),.. ])
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=dataSchema)
```